# Making a loop work in C sharp and queuing messages in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, loops

I have the following code where I am attempting to queue loads of messages on my rabbitmq queue to test it and see if I can break it. I do not get why it is not working:

What I am trying to do in the loop is to make it post the message 4 times and then finish. What could be the error in this code?

Code:

```
using System;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using System.Text;

class Send
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                // for (int myInt = 0; myInt < 699;)

                int myInt = 1;
                do 
                while (myInt <= 4)
                {
                    //  channel.QueueDeclare("test", false, false, false, null);
                    //int myInt = 0;
                    //while (myInt < 10) ;
                    string message = "Hello World!";
                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                    channel.BasicPublish("", "test", null, body);
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
                    Console.Read();
                    //Environment.Exit(0);
                    return;
                }
                //myInt++;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have updated the code to:

```
using System;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using System.Text;

class Send
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())

    {   for (int myInt = 100; myInt <= 100000 ; myInt++)
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())


            while (myInt <= 100000)
                {
                    string message = "Hello World!";
                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                    channel.BasicPublish("", "hello", null, body);
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
                    Console.Read();
                    myInt++;
                }


                //myInt++;
            }
        //myInt++;
    //return;
        //  myInt++;
    }

}
```

But it is still not working.

Comment: I don't get what "it is not working" means. Post a [mcve] or at least actual vs expected results.

Comment: You `return` from `Main()` the first time the loop runs

Answer (score 1):

You put the return statement inside the while loop, which causes the program to terminate after one iteration of the loop. Also, you forgot to increment the variable `myInt` so you would be running into the problem of an infinite loop even if you move the return statement. In addition, you don't need the `do` keyword. Your while loop should look something like this:

```
while (myInt <= 4)
    {      
        string message = "Hello World!";
        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        channel.BasicPublish("", "test", null, body);
        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
        Console.Read();
        myInt++;
    }
```

And your return statement should be the last line in the `Main` function.

Comment: No problem. Cheers!